# Find students who registered for both of two courses

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display student Id who registered for the course 100, 101. If they registered for both the courses then display the student id once.

```
SELECT studid FROM registration
WHERE courseid='100' or courseid='101';
```

I don't know how to check the condition - "If they registered for both the courses then display the student id once."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT studid FROM registration WHERE courseid IN ('100', 101');
```

or `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT studid FROM registration WHERE courseid IN ('100', '101') GROUP BY studid;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the condition where a student has registered for both courses, rather than just either one of them, you also need to check the number of courses registered:

```
select studid
from   registration
where  courseid in (100, 101)
group by studid having count(distinct courseid) = 2;
```

(I've counted the `distinct` course IDs just in case a student can register twice for the same course. If that isn't possible in your data model, `count(*)` would do fine.)

Or, you could use `intersect` to find students that occur in both sets:

```
select studid
from   registration
where  courseid = 100
intersect
select studid
from   registration
where  courseid = 101;
```

Or just for fun, collect all coursids for each student into a collection and then check whether `(100,101)` is a subset of that:

```
select studid
from   registration
group by studid
having ku$_objnumset(100,101) submultiset of cast(collect(courseid) as ku$_objnumset);
```

I've used the built-in `ku$_objnumset` which I found by querying `all_coll_types` (it belongs to `SYS` and is used in `dbms_metadata`), but you can create your own, e.g.

```
create or replace type number_tt as table of number;
```