# How to select a member that have borrowed all books

Tags: sql, oracle

- MEMBER (mid primary key, name, birthdate)
- BORROW (bid primary key, copyid, mid)
- COPIES (copyid primary key, bookid)
- BOOK (bookid primary key, title, themecode)
- THEME (themecode primary key, label)

The question is:

"For a given theme,list the members name and birthdate who have borrowed all the books of this theme."

I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    t.label, m.name, m.tel
FROM 
    Theme t, Member m, Book b, Copies c, Borrow b1
WHERE 
    t.themecode = b.themecode 
    AND b.bookid = c.bookid 
    AND b1.copyid = c.copyid  
    AND b1.mid = m.mid 
    AND t.label = 'Action'
```

and it returned all members who borrowed this book of the theme, but I want only members who borrowed ALL books of this theme

Comment: yep sorry i forgot it, i edited my post.

Comment: Look for 'relational division'.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019723/230471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a granular list of Members and all Borrows they have had for a certain theme.

You want to see how many distinct Books a member has borrowed.

You also want to see how many total distinct books there are for a given theme.

You only want to list the members that have borrowed as many distinct books as there are total books for a theme.

```
SELECT m.name,m.tel
FROM Theme t,Member m, Book b,Copies c,Borrow b1
WHERE t.themecode=b.themecode AND 
b.bookid=c.bookid AND
b1.copyid=c.copyid AND
b1.mid=m.mid AND 
t.label='Action' 
Group by m.name, m.tel-- distinct users
Having count(distinct bookid) = -- number of distinct books each person borrowed
(Select count(distinct bookid) from Theme t, Book b WHERE t.themecode=b.themecode and t.label= 'Action') --total number of distinct books for your Theme
```

Also comments/answers are right you should use explicit joins I'm just helping you add the logic to your script and explain why it works.

Comment: it says not a group by expression idk why

Comment: @elio I guessed on your specific RDBMS updated above

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `HAVING` clause with `COUNT` aggregation combining tables through `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.label,m.name,m.tel
  FROM Theme t
  LEFT JOIN Book b ON t.themecode=b.themecode 
   AND t.label='Action' 
  LEFT JOIN Copies c ON b.bookid=c.bookid
  LEFT JOIN Borrow b1 ON b1.copyid=c.copyid  
  LEFT JOIN Member m ON b1.mid=m.mid
 GROUP BY t.label,m.name,m.tel
 HAVING count(distinct b.bookid)= count(t.themecode)
```

Comment: I presumed t.themecode was specific to each label.  OP makes us guess.  So Action label would have one distinct themecode, making the count always 1 right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to get the number of books with theme 'Action'. 
Join all the tables properly, group by member and count the number of distinct books they have borrowed and compare it with the result of the CTE:

```
with cte as(
  select count(*) counter from book where themecode = (
    select themecode from theme where label = 'Action'  
  )
)
select t.label, m.name, m.birthdate
from member m
inner join borrow br on br.mid = m.mid
inner join copies c on c.copyid = br.copyid
inner join book b on b.bookid = c.bookid
inner join theme t on t.themecode = b.themecode
where t.label = 'Action'
group by t.label, m.mid, m.name, m.birthdate
having count(distinct b.bookid) = (select counter from cte)
```