# Sql query to display

Tags: sql

Write a query to display student Id who registered for the course 1001, 1005. If they registered for both the courses then display the student id once. Sort the result by student Id.

Comment: Literally a duplicate question here... [Find students who registered for both of two courses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017302/find-students-who-registered-for-both-of-two-courses)

Answer (score 0):

Seems an awfully lot like a SQL course question, but...

```sql
postgres=# select * from student;
 id | course 
----+--------
  1 |   1001
  1 |   1005
  2 |   1001
  2 |   1003
  3 |   1003
  4 |   1001
  4 |   1005
(7 rows)

postgres=# select distinct id from student where course in (1001, 1005) order by id;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  4
(3 rows)
```